# Running a command on each file from a directory if it ends in a certain extension

Tags: powershell, windows-10

I"m trying to run a convert all of my .ipynb files within a directory to .pdf using this command:

```
 ipython nbconvert {FILE} --to pdf
```

where {FILE} is the filename.

I'm trying to find all .ipynb files within a directory and its subdirs and then apply the above command to each file using powershell.

Looking around stackoverflow I put together the first part, but I"m not sure about the second part:

```
Get-ChildItem C:\Users\yomog\Desktop\FAST AI\courses-master *.ipynb     -recurse |
    Foreach-Object {
       ipython nbconvert {FILE} --to pdf
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors? File not found perhaps?

Comment: Hi. Actuallythe {FILE} portion is sudo code, I couldnt figure out how to acess the each file found by the Get-ChildItem.

Comment: I'd give replacing `ipython nbconvert {FILE} --to pdf` with `ipython nbconvert $_.FullPath --to pdf` a shot. Might wanna make sure you have backups of the files before testing however. I'm not familiar with nbconvert and have no clue what it really does.

Comment: Ops, too early in the morning still `$_.FullPath` in my example should be `$_.FullName`.

Comment: @notjustme  Thanks for the update. I kept getting an error with FullPath and I was thinking it was the `nbconvert` portion. Got it working now  =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to quote pathes containing spaces

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\yomog\Desktop\FAST AI\courses-master *.ipynb" -Recurse |
    Foreach-Object {
       & ipython nbconvert "$($_.FullName)" --to pdf
}
```

Comment: Can you verify that the quoting is actually required? From my testing paths with spaces are passed in as a single string without the need for quotes or the forced evaluation. I don't have `ipython nbconvert` to test with but using a `python myscript.py $_.FullName` is working fine for me when there are spaces. I also tested with a .net console app for kicks. Perhaps it's the additional arguments after the file name that require this?

Comment: I neither have that `ipython`, but see the [call operator](https://ss64.com/ps/call.html) and consider that in the powershell console tabbing a folder with spaces will automatically by quoted.

Comment: Yeah I tested it with python and additional arguments and it seems to process appropriately without quotes. I imagine this is because powershell is object based and can tell the difference between two separate arguments in an array and a single string argument with a space. I would fully expect bash or cmd to necessitate the quotes.

Answer (score 1):

The object being returned to the pipeline can be accessed as `$_`. Since it will be returning IO.FileInfo objects your best bet is probably to replace `{FILE}` with `$_.FullName`